# Get UTC timestamp from time zone aware datetime object in Python

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I have a datetime object that I created with`datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))`.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that my datetime object is NOT naïve. How do I convert this datetime object to a UTC timestamp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `datetime.astimezone` to get the same datetime in UTC (or any other timezone).

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
non_naive_datetime_obj.astimezone(pytz.utc).timestamp()
```